# PyO3 implement python iterable class in Rust

Tags: python, rust, cpython, pyo3

I've [found example](https://docs.rs/pyo3/0.13.2/pyo3/class/iter/trait.PyIterProtocol.html) of how to implement PyIterProtocol in Rust.

```
use pyo3::prelude::*;
use pyo3::PyIterProtocol;
use pyo3::class::iter::IterNextOutput;

#[pyclass]
struct Iter {
    count: usize
}

#[pyproto]
impl PyIterProtocol for Iter {
    fn __next__(mut slf: PyRefMut<Self>) -> IterNextOutput<usize, &'static str> {
        if slf.count < 5 {
            slf.count += 1;
            IterNextOutput::Yield(slf.count)
        } else {
            IterNextOutput::Return("Ended")
        }
    }
}
```

but I cannot figure out how to implement a container class that is iterable but is not a iterator itself. Essentially I want to be able to decompose my object in Python like

```
x, y, z = my_object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the user guide on Iterator Types](https://pyo3.rs/v0.13.2/class/protocols.html#iterator-types):

> In many cases you'll have a distinction between the type being iterated over (i.e. the *iterable*) and the iterator it provides. In this case, you should implement `PyIterProtocol` for both the iterable and the iterator, but the iterable only needs to support `__iter__()` while the iterator must support both `__iter__()` and `__next__()`.